# How to create a new variable by comparing two rows with multiple key columns in common

Tags: r

Lets say I have the following df:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id pair game round win target_var
1.   1.   1.    1.  0.         1.
1.   1.   1.    2.  1.         1.
1.   1.   2.    1.  1.         1.
1.   1.   2.    2.  0.         0.
2.   1.   1.    1.  1.         0.
2.   1.   1.    2.  0.         0.
2.   1.   2.    1.  0.         1.
2.   1.   2.    2.  1.         0.
")
```

which represents gameplay between two people. I want to know when `target var` is `TRUE` for both players, neither player, winner only, or loser only. To do this, I need to make sure that I compare the two rows with a different `id`, but the same `pair`, `game`, and `round`. When I identify those two rows, I check `target var` and `win` (binary, winner == 1) to determine which, if either player, shows `target var == TRUE`. I then want to place the result in a new row such that:

```
df_outcome <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id pair game round win target_var desire
1.   1.   1.    1.  0.         1.    'l'
1.   1.   1.    2.  1.         1.    'w'
1.   1.   2.    1.  1.         1.    'b'
1.   1.   2.    2.  0.         0.    'n'
2.   1.   1.    1.  1.         0.    'l'
2.   1.   1.    2.  0.         0.    'w'
2.   1.   2.    1.  0.         1.    'b'
2.   1.   2.    2.  1.         0.    'n'
")
```

I have a very long, inefficient way of doing this, but I have to perform similar comparisons many times, so I am looking for a tidy method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here´s a solution with `dplyr::case_when()` for good readability:

```
library(dplyr)

# ------------------
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                     pair = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                     game = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                     round = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
                     win = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
                     target_var = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
                     
                     desire = c("l", "w", "b", "n", "l", "w", "b", "n")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
                class = "data.frame")

# ------------------
df <- mutate(
  df, .by = c(game, round),
  
  outcome = case_when(
    all(target_var == 1) ~ "b",
    all(target_var == 0) ~ "n",
    target_var == win ~ "w",
    target_var != win ~ "l"))

# ------------------
  id pair game round win target_var desire outcome
1  1    1    1     1   0          1      l       l
2  1    1    1     2   1          1      w       w
3  1    1    2     1   1          1      b       b
4  1    1    2     2   0          0      n       n
5  2    1    1     1   1          0      l       l
6  2    1    1     2   0          0      w       w
7  2    1    2     1   0          1      b       b
8  2    1    2     2   1          0      n       n
```